# cannot send contents to /html/body/p under iframe for rich text editior

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, automation

In this editor, when you input contents, everything goes to tag `<p>`, but the system could not recognise `/html/body/p`, so I use `/html/body` or switch to active element, either of them dont work.

```
            driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@title,'ALT')]"))
            driver.switch_to_active_element()
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.execute_script("document.body.innerHTML = '<br>'")
            webElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
            webElement.send_keys(developreqTestData["inputOne"][inputNotes])
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.switch_to_default_content()
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: I use PhantomJS 1.9.2

Answer (score -1):

driver.execute_script("document.body.innerHTML = 'your contents'")

this works